# My hard drive says 5tb but finder can only see 320gb?

Tags: finder, crash, trash

The drive has verified ok, disk repair sees no issue. I did a search in the Finder as advised. FOLDERS + CONTENTS <1 and it returned all my empty folders after a duplicate clean.

Then I said "Move to Trash" and the Finder crashed halfway through the move. But it also seems the command emptied full folders as well. And now I'm in no mans land. They are gone from the Finder but the drive says they are still there. I did hidden folders and there is not much. Screen shot attached. [image: hidden folders]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us a picture of the hard drive partitions in Disk Utility (search for it via spotlight). I can see in the finder window that there are multiple other drives or connected to the computer eg. "RIGPA 2" and "RIGPA" it may be that the drive is 5tb, but the partition you are on is less

Comment: Please post the output of the Terminal command command `diskutil list` by [editing your question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/325155/edit) with the results.

Comment: So that we can assist you please be as clear as possible about what you have done and the problems you are seeing. Telling us the Mac you are using and which version of the OS. might also be helpful. Also, it looks like you have several drives connected to the Mac. Try disconnecting all the other drives so it is only the internal drive and the drive giving you problems.

Open "Disk Utility" and show us the partition map for the drive. Also show us, as has already been asked, the output of `diskutil list`.

Then. we might be able to assist you.